# Test class or Restclass http methods (POST/PUT/GET)

Tags: unit-test

Can anyone help me to write the test class for my below Rest apex class:

```
@RestResource(UrlMapping='/Onboarding/Accounts/*')
global with sharing class rest_Accounts {

    @HttpGet
    global static Account getAccount() {
        RestRequest request = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse response = RestContext.response;
        String externalId = request.requestURI.substring(request.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

        return [
                SELECT Id,
                        External_ID__c,
                        AccountSource,
                        Active__c,
                        Alarm__c,
                        Anticipated_Avg_Num_Debits_Month_c__c,
                        Application_fee_consent_DateDate__c,
                        Application_fee_consent_IP_address__c,
                        Application_fee_consent_Signer__c,
                        Approved_For_Sync__c,
                       
                        
                        __c,
                        Date_of_Deed__c,
                        Deed_SSN__c,
                        Description,
                        Doing_Business_As__c,
                        Esign_Consent_Date__c,
                        Esign_Consent_IP_Address__c,
                        Esign_Consent_Signer__c,
                        Esign_Consent_Signer__r.ContactExternal_ID__c,
                        Est_Payroll_Expense_Month__c,
                        Est_Payroll_Expense_Week__c,
                        Federal_Tax_ID__c,
                        Federal_Tax_ID_Type__c,
                        How_Did_You_Hear_About_Us__c,
                        Individual__c,
                        Initial_Deposit_Amount__c,
                        Initial_Deposit_Source__c,
                        Insurance_Company__c,
                        Insurance_Policy_Expiration__c,
                        Insurance_Policy_Number__c,
                        Inventory_Management_System__c,
                        IsDeleted,
                        Location_Cash_Pickup__c,
                        Location_Occupation__c,
                        MasterRecordId,
                        NAICS_Code__c,
                        Name,
                        NumberOfEmployees,
                        Organization_Account__c,
                        Organization_Account__r.External_ID__c,
                        Other_IMS__c,
                        Other_POS__c,
                        
                        State_License_Expiration_Date__c,
                        State_of_License__c,
                        State_of_Registration__c,
                        State_Registration_License_ID__c,
                        SystemModstamp,
                        TCPA_Consent_Date__c,
                        TCPA_Consent_IP_Address__c,
                        TCPA_Consent_Signer__c,
                        TCPA_Consent_Signer__r.ContactExternal_ID__c,
                        Terms_Conditions_Date__c,
                        Terms_Conditions_IP_Address__c,
                        Tier_Sub_Category__c,
                        Transactable_Prospect__c,
                        Type,
                        Update_Required__c,
                        International_Transactions_Needed__c,
                        User_Supplied_State__c,
                        Are_you_using_Private_Security__c,
                        Online_Properties__c
                FROM Account
                WHERE External_ID__c = :externalId
                LIMIT 1
        ];
    }

    @HttpPut
    global static void saveAccounts() {
        RestRequest request = RestContext.request;
        String requestPayload = request.requestBody.toString();
        List<Account> accounts = (List<Account>) JSON.deserialize(requestPayload, List<Account>.class);
        List<String> errors = new List<String>();

        for (Account acc: accounts) {
            try {
                upsert acc External_ID__c;
            } catch (DmlException ex) {
                errors.add('upsert account ' + acc.External_ID__c + ' failed: ' + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }

        if (errors.size() > 0) {
            String msg = String.join(errors, ',');
            throw new OnboardingUpsertException(msg);
        }
    }


    @HttpPost
    global static Account[] findAccounts() {
        RestRequest request = RestContext.request;
        String requestPayload = request.requestBody.toString();
        List<String> accountExternalIdList = (List<String>) JSON.deserialize(requestPayload, List<String>.class);

        Account[] results = [
                SELECT  Id,
                        External_ID__c,
                        AccountSource,
                        Active__c,
                        NumberOfEmployees,
                        Organization_Account__c,
                        Organization_Account__r.External_ID__c,
                        Other_IMS__c,
                        Other_POS__c,
                        Other_Corporate_Structure_Type__c,
                        Paid_On_Behalf_Of__c,
                        Paid_On_Behalf_Of__r.External_ID__c,
                        ParentId,
                        Parent.External_ID__c,
                        Phone_Alternate__c,
                        Phone_Fax__c,
                        Phone,
                        Point_of_Sale_System__c,
                        Preapproved_Partner__c,
                        Privacy_Policy_Date__c,
                        Privacy_Policy_IP_Address__c,
                        Privacy_Policy_Signer__c,
                        Privacy_Policy_Signer__r.ContactExternal_ID__c,
                        Product_ID__c,
                        Program_ID__c,
                        Program__c,
                        Program__r.Program_ID__c,
                        Projected_Annual_Gross_Receipts__c,
                        Referral_Code__c,
                        Relationship_Share_Account__c,
                        Relationship_Share_Account__r.External_ID__c,
                        Safe__c,
                        Estimated_Yearly_Sales_Tax__c,
                        Security_Camera__c,
                        Security_Description__c,
                        Sellers_Permit_Number__c,
                        Seperate_BankAccount_Location__c,
                        ShippingStreet,
                        ShippingCity,
                        ShippingState
                FROM Account
                WHERE External_ID__c IN :accountExternalIdList
                AND Active__c = TRUE
        ];
        return results;
    }

}
```

Many thanks in advance!

**

- Test class i have written is:

**

```
@IsTest
public class rest_Accounts_Test {
    
    @testSetup
    static void dataSetup() {
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Name = 'Testing';
        acc.Industry = 'Agriculture';
      //  External_ID__c= ''
        insert acc;
        
    }
    
    static testMethod void testGet() {
        Account acc = [ SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 1 ];
        RestRequest req = new RestRequest(); 
        RestResponse res = new RestResponse();             
        req.requestURI = '/services/apexrest/Account/' + acc.Id;
        req.httpMethod = 'GET';
        RestContext.request = req;
        RestContext.response= res;
        Account acctResp = rest_Accounts.getAccount();
        system.assertEquals(acctResp.Name, 'Testing');
    }
    
    @isTest
    static void updateBOClassMethod(){
   Test.startTest();
 Account sHOppRec= [SELECT Id,Name From Account Where Name ='Testing' Limit 1];
system.debug('sHOppRec : ' + sHOppRec);        
   SingleRequestMock fakeResponse1 = new SingleRequestMock(sHOppRec.Id,
                                                system.today(),
                                                 'Prospecting',
                                                 system.today()+1,
                                                   25);
    String JsonMsg=JSON.serialize(fakeResponse1);
        system.debug('JsonMsg : ' + JsonMsg);
   RestRequest req = new RestRequest(); 
   RestResponse res = new RestResponse();

    req.requestURI = '/services/apexrest/DemoUrl';  //Request URL
    req.httpMethod = 'POST';//HTTP Request Type
    req.requestBody = Blob.valueof(JsonMsg);
    RestContext.request = req;
    RestContext.response= res;
  List<Account> acctResp = rest_Accounts.findAccounts();
    Test.stopTest();
}
    
  
     static testMethod void testPut() {
        Account acc = [ SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 1 ];
        RestRequest req = new RestRequest(); 
        RestResponse res = new RestResponse();             
        req.requestURI = '/services/apexrest/Account/' + acc.Id;
        req.httpMethod = 'GET';
        RestContext.request = req;
        RestContext.response= res;
        List<Account> acctResp = testRestAccounts_Vedha.findAccounts();
       // system.assertEquals(acctResp.Name, 'Testing');
    } 
    
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! How *exactly* has what you have tried not worked (e.g., share exact error text, unexpected behavior). Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/377957/edit) your question to add those details.

Comment: error1:
System.JSONException: Malformed JSON: Expected '[' at the beginning of List/Set

Error 2: System.NullPointerException: Argument cannot be null. Class.rest_Accounts_Test.testPut: line 59, column 1

Comment: Thank you for responding, but as I stated in my comment you should *edit your question* to add that information. It keeps it all in one place for anyone reading, which makes it easier to follow and understand, and make it easier for someone to help.

Comment: Thanks @Moonpie for your response!
I was able to fix the errors,